# Having trouble switching scenes in javaFX and Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have 2 views:
one with a button that says "move to second view" and another one with a label.
I am trying to switch between the 2 scenes by clicking the button.

For this I wrote the following code: (The Controller class is the controller of the first scene)

```
public class Controller {
    public void switchToSecondScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getScene().getWindow());

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

The Problem is that the editor tells me that it cannot resolve method `getScene()`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How casting to a class works, you add the thing you want to cast it to in brackets in front of it.
The result that is returned is cast to the thing between the brackets

```
// Simple casting, otherThing gets cast to Foo
var something = (Foo)otherThing;

// Whatever is returned by getThing() gets cast to Foo
var something = (Foo)otherThing.getThing();

// Whatever is returned by makeThing() gets cast to Foo
var something = (Foo)otherThing.getThing().makeThing();
```

So in short, whatever you would want to assign to the variable in this example gets cast to the thing you want to cast it to.

So if we dissect your code with this logic:

```
(Stage)((Node)event.getScene().getWindow());

// assigning to individual variables.
Node window = (Node)event.getScene().getWindow();
Stage stage = (Stage)window;
```

So whatever gets returned by `getWindow()` you cast to Stage. That's not the logic you want. Also, you're missing a vital step in your code. You need to call `getSource()` first on your event object.

`event.getSource()` returns a `Node` object(hopefully, to bullet proof do an instanceof check before casting).
The `Node` object gives you access to the methods you need.

```
final Node source = (Node)event.getSource();
final Stage stage = (Stage)source.getScene().getWindow();
```

Try to assign variables to their own types when casting through layers, to aid you in deducing the logic, and finding errors. When you nest casts it can become a mess. Take a look at a working one liner of your code when implemented properly compared against the two above. Which one is clearer?:

```
(Stage)(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
```